# Iterating through subcontainers with Angular and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, angularjs

I'm curious to know the best way to iterate through mongodb with angular to get all domains for a given customer.

Here's my JSON from MongoDB:

```
    {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "513568dae4b08eabdba2eb63"
},
"name": "Sofa King",
"contactPrimaryName": "Richard Cranium",
"contactPrimaryPhone": "410 555-1212",
"contactPrimaryEmail": "me@mysite.com",
"PrimaryAddress": "123 Any Street\nApt. 17",
"contactPrimaryCity": "Nashville",
"contactPrimaryState": "TN",
"contactPrimaryZip": "22222",
"site": "http://www.mysite.com",  //ignore, replacing with domains
"domains": [
    {
        "url": "http://www.mysite.com",
        "ns1": "ns1.mydns.com",
        "ns2": "ns2.mydns.com",
        "registered": "2011-01-01",
        "expires": "2014-01-01"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://www.myother.com",
        "ns1": "ns1.mydns.com",
        "ns2": "ns2.mydns.com",
        "registered": "2012-02-02",
        "expires": "2015-02-02"
    }
]
```

I know that I can get Customer details with the following:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
    <td><a href="{{customer.site}}" target="_blank">{{customer.name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{customer.contactPrimaryName}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.contactPrimaryPhone}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.contactPrimaryEmail}}</td>
```

But I'm not sure how to get domain URLs for a given customer.

My goal is to have a customer list on one page with a button to view the domains for that customer. When viewing the domains for a given customer then having the ability to add a domain.

Answer (score 4):

You should just be able to iterate over the "domains" array for the current customer:

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
...
    <td>
        <div data-ng-repeat="domain in customer.domains">
            // Do stuff in here with the domain for that customer
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'll try this now. The though of nesting an ng-repeat completely escaped me. If I go 3 or 4 documents deep would I just continue to add DIVs or is there another way? - Curious now...

Comment: You can go just about as deep as you want with ng-repeat. There may be a limit, but I don't think so. I've seems repeats at least 5 or 10 deep, including recursive repeats, and they all work.

Comment: Did this answer work out for you? If so, can you accept the answer?